# Update a progressbar in a thread

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a Python code where I create a progressbar. The Tkinter environment is created in the Gui function with the progressbar and it is launched as a thread. Then in an other thread I calculate the value that the progressbar must have, but the problem is that I dont know how to update the Gui thread with the new value of the progressbar. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import thread

def Gui(): 
   root = tk.Tk()
   root.geometry('450x450')
   root.title('Hanix Downloader')

   button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Salir', width=25,command=root.destroy)
   button1.pack()

   s = ttk.Style()
   s.theme_use('clam')
   s.configure("green.Horizontal.TProgressbar", foreground='green', background='green')

   mpb = ttk.Progressbar(root,style="green.Horizontal.TProgressbar",orient ="horizontal",length = 200, mode ="determinate")
   mpb.pack()
   mpb["maximum"] = 3620
   mpb["value"] = 1000

   root.mainloop()

def main():
while True:
    #Calculate the new value of the progress bar.
    mpb["value"] = 100 #Does not work
    root.update_idletasks()#Does not work
    #Do some other tasks.


if __name__ == '__main__':
thread.start_new_thread( Gui,() )
thread.start_new_thread( main,() )
```

The error I get is that mpb and root do no exist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many questions and answers on this site related to tkinter, threads, and the progressbar. Have you don't any research before asking this question? Also, you need to fix the indentation in your code example.

Comment: Yes, I have looked to some post and questions, but I am unable to solve it, sorry... I have spent 5 hours with this.

Comment: Did you get error message (traceback) when you run in console? Always show it in question. You should get error because `mpb` and `root` are local variables which exist only in `Gui()` but not in `main()`

Comment: Yes, I get an error message saying that mpb and root do not exit.

Comment: @Andermutu you always add error message in questions - it explain all your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get error because `mpb` and `root` are local variables which exist only in `Gui` but not in `main`. You have to use `global` to inform both functions to use global variables - and then `main` will have access to `mpb` created in `Gui`

I also add `time.sleep(1)` before `while True:` because sometimes `main` may start faster then `Gui` and it may not find `mpb` (because `Gui` had no time to create progressbar)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import _thread
import time

def Gui():
   global root, mpb

   root = tk.Tk()

   button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Exit', command=root.destroy)
   button1.pack()

   mpb = ttk.Progressbar(root, mode="determinate")
   mpb.pack()

   mpb["maximum"] = 3000
   mpb["value"] = 1000

   root.mainloop()


def main():
    global root, mpb

    time.sleep(1)

    while True:
        mpb["value"] += 100
        #root.update_idletasks() # works without it

        #Do some other tasks.
        time.sleep(0.2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _thread.start_new_thread(Gui, ())
    _thread.start_new_thread(main, ())
```

Tested on Python 3.6.2, Linux Mint 18.2

---

**EDIT:** more precisely: you need `global` only in `Gui` because it assigns values to variables
`root = ...`, `mpb = ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are awesome. However when I push exit button I get this error message in my console: RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

Comment: `exit` closes window but thread `main` is still running - you have to stop this thread before `root.destroy`. You could use `while running:` in `main` and set `runnig = False` in `Gui`. Working with threads can be complicated and sometimes it is easier to use `root.after()` instead thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot... you are the best.